# How can I show changes to the build when running a test task?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to configure a Jenkins server that will have separated Jobs to run the building of our projects and to test them.

The problem is that when we run the test jobs, they don´t automatically poll for the changes in the build. 
This data can be easily found in our build Jobs, but the test jobs don´t have a polling.log (no source code, so no changes, these Jobs are mstest Jobs and doesn´t build anything).

We want to be able to show our developers what are the changes in the source code of the Project (between the last two builds) so they know who could be responsable for breaking the tests.

I am not sure if I made myself clear, please feel free to ask me if you need more information to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work for manually-started builds, but if you trigger your test job off a successful build job, then the test job instance will show which build job triggered it.  This provides good traceability.

Also consider the [Blame Upstream Committers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blame+Upstream+Committers+Plugin) or [Claim](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin) plugins, they might get you part-way there.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks a lot for your answer. Quick follow up question:

The problem we have tracing like that is that our main Project has 3 different build processes, so the first runs and if succeded, the second one runs and if succeded, the third one does the same thing. After that we trigger lots of different kinds of tests to the whole solution, and it would be very cool to be able to show a log for the changes in the three building projects.

Both plugins seem very promising, I wonder if I will be able to acomplish this.Thanks!

Comment: You want a more complex flow then.  Job (kick-off) triggers all three of your various builds, and then use the [Join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) to join all three builds to the test job.  That should provide you with your traceability, though testers will have to click several links to find the exact code that changed.